# Bitbucket Pipeline Build Is Generated but when trying to install from device its shows "App not install"

Tags: android, continuous-integration, bitbucket, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

Here's the pipeline configuration which I added on my bitbucket project.

but when I try to make a build directly through android studio it is working fine, but with pipeline when I try to download from bitbucket-artifcats then app not installed error is showing when I try to install the apk

```
`image: androidsdk/android-30

pipelines:
  default:                # pipeline definition for all branches
        - step:           # step to build Android debug application
            name: Android Debug Application
            script:
              - ./gradlew assembleDebug 
            artifacts:
              - app/build/outputs/**        # artifacts are files that are produced by a step`
```

I want to make a build in Android (.apk) file whenever I pushed the code to the specific branch.
Its actually happening but app not installed error is showing when trying to install the app.

where I'm doing wrong, anyone please help.?